# Do merchants ever run out of items, or can they sell items off their shelves?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Do merchants ever run out of inventory, or do they regenerate it after a certain amount of time? Also, does the merchant ever sell any of the items off of their shelves, or is that just for show?

Shelves for reference:

[image: Ref]

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36529/do-shops-npcs-houses-replenish-their-contents-after-an-act-of-thievery    http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35529/how-often-do-merchants-replenish-their-gold-supply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Merchants restock their inventory after 2 days in game.

The items on the shelves can be bought.

http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Containers#Merchant_Chests

> All merchants in the game (with the exception of Hunters, Peddlers,
>   and skooma dealers) have a merchant chest containing the merchant's
>   gold and the goods they have available for sale. The chest does not
>   contain the merchant's entire inventory — **merchants will also sell
>   some items sitting out in the store** and unequipped items in their
>   personal inventory — and also is not the only source of merchant gold
>   — any personal gold will be added to the merchant's available gold.

Comment: "*All merchants in the game... have a merchant chest...*" Related: [What is this strange “Do Not Delete” object? And does it have a use?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/42341/4797)